# Referencing a range using hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm looking for a solution of hyperlinking a cell.

For example:

- On **Sheet one** I have details

  - for XYZ from B1 to D5
  - for ABC B7 to D11.
- On **sheet two** I have XYZ and ABC. If I click in sheet two XYZ then the entire details should open and same for rest.

Currently I'm able to hyperlink from B1 to D5, B7 to D11 and so on.

I'm facing problem if I insert two rows for XYZ: now XYZ is from B1 to D7 and ABC has gone two columns down from B9 to D13. Here the hyperlink is not referring to B1 to D7. It is still referring B1 to D5.

Answer (score 0):

To make your hyperlinks following their target you need to use the `Hyperlink` function:˛

`=HYPERLINK("[name of workbook]"&ADDRESS(ROW(B1),COLUMN(B1),1,1,"Sheet One")&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(D5),COLUMN(D5),1,1))`

This way link will be updated as you insert / delete rows / columns.